# Авторизация на сайте для Android

Tags: android

Напишите, пожалуйста, пример функции авторизации на сайте и парсинг страницы.

Comment: Звучит как "дайте ключ от комнаты где деньги лежат". Такие вопросы здесь не приветствуются. Вопрос должен содержать конкретную проблему, а не просьбу написать за вас что-то

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Начиная с SDK 2.0 авторизация удобно осуществляется с помощью класса [AccountManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html). Примеры работы встречаются в Google:

- [Android: Account Manager: Step by Step](http://www.finalconcept.com.au/article/view/android-account-manager-step-by-step-1)
- [Authenticating against AppEngine using the Android AccountManager](http://gnuc.in/resources/archives/1404).